# Kendo autocomplete list not dropping down when using Selenium send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, kendo-ui

I have an input element with Kendo UI autocomplete wired to it:

```
intputElement.kendoAutoComplete({
dataSource: ...,
filter: "contains",
select: function (e) {alert("you selected an option");}
...
})
```

When I manually type text into the input field, the list of auto-completions drops down and I can select an option from it. When I click/select it, I see the alert message.

When using Selenium's `send_keys` (python bindings) to enter the same text, the list is loaded into the DOM but it is hidden. I can wait for the option's presence and, by using Selenium's JS executor feature, I can click on the option from the dropdown but it seems that it doesn't actually trigger a select event. I don't see the alarm popping up.

I tried sending `Keys.RETURN` and `Keys.TAB` to the input field to somehow get the dropdown list to be visible thinking that maybe the invisibility makes Kendo ignore the click on the option, but no luck there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced difficulty with auto complete options. I tried initially clicking in input box and entering the character by character with sleep. its worked well in my case. below is the logic used in Java, so you can try in python.

```
// string value which is needed to enter in input box to display auto complete options
String str="murali seleniumtrainer";

    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).click();

    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){

        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));

            Thread.sleep(200);

    }
// click on required option from auto complete.. as per requirement
```

Thank You,
Murali